# How to change the first line of a 2d array with the last line?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, swap

So I have an 2-D array `A[4][7]`:

```
1 8 4 6 9 8 7
1 1 1 9 8 8 5
1 1 1 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

How can I change the first line with the last one?
To look like this:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 9 8 8 5
1 1 1 0 1 1 1
1 8 4 6 9 8 7
```

In Java

Answer (score 1):

You just need to swap the first row with the last row using the common swapping algorithm. Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class NameSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] array = {
                { 1, 2, 3 },
                { 2, 3, 4 },
                { 3, 4, 5 }
        };
        System.out.println("Original array: \n" + Arrays.deepToString(array));

        int[] temp = array[0];
        array[0] = array[array.length - 1];
        array[array.length - 1] = temp;
        System.out.println("Updated array: \n" + Arrays.deepToString(array));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Original array: 
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
Updated array: 
[[3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create standalone method for this purpose:

```java
public static void swapRows(int[][] arr, int row1, int row2) {
    int[] temp = arr[row1];
    arr[row1] = arr[row2];
    arr[row2] = temp;
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = {
            {1, 8, 4, 6, 9, 8, 7},
            {1, 1, 1, 9, 8, 8, 5},
            {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}};

    swapRows(arr, 0, 3);

    // output
    Arrays.stream(arr).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 9, 8, 8, 5]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 8, 4, 6, 9, 8, 7]
```